# How do I use the input received from the user from one class in a different class, using JOptionPane?

Tags: java

This is my first class and I would like to know if I could use whatever is being inputed by the user in a different class. How would I go about doing that?

[image: This is my first class and I would like to know if I could use whatever is being inputed by the user in a different class. How would I go about doing that?]

Comment: Hello Nick, welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to include the code instead of an image as that won't help any future viewers. Also please include a clear problem statement. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17628525)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use the variable as is in a different class. The variable is instantiated in a method and will stay within that method, getting removed when the method stops executing. That is without me knowing how the other class looks. You sure could pass it to a method or constructor of the other class within the `main()` method in order to use it there. Though you'd need to show how the other class looks and what methods it has for that.